# Trying to hide <p> tags by default with state react es6

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following static view:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Champ extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={this.props.champ.file} />
        <p>Name: {this.props.champ.name } </p>
        <p>Role: { this.props.champ.role } </p>
        <p>Difficulty: { this.props.champ.diff } </p>
        <p>Price: { this.props.champ.price } </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I want to change it so that only the images are visible when the page is loaded and when they are hovered over the information will fade in.

I want to do this by having all the `<p>` tags that contain the info to be hidden by default when the page opens and do it with state.

I thought I could do something like making them into a const

```
const x = <p>Name: {this.props.champ.name } </p>
    <p>Role: { this.props.champ.role } </p>
    <p>Difficulty: { this.props.champ.diff } </p>
    <p>Price: { this.props.champ.price } </p>


this.state = { x.style.visibilty = 'hidden'};
```

}

But I'm actually unsure of how to do this. I'm only now learning state and I've never used hidden before. Thank you.

Comment: State should be written like this `this.state = { visible: true }` and simply create a function that renders all p tags if `this.state.visible === true`

Comment: @Raymond suggestion should work fine

Answer (score 4):

State should express the state but not hold rendered content. So you just need a `detailsVisible` flag or something in state which you toggle `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` using `setState({ detailsVisible: true | false })`, then you can use `this.state.detailsVisible` to render out the `<p>` tags or not. To show and hide them all together it would be convenient to put them in a wrapper element or component and toggle the visibility of it using an expression:

```
class Champ extends React.Component {
  state = { detailsVisible: false };
  handleMouseEnter = e => this.setState({ detailsVisible: true });
  handleMouseLeave = e => this.setState({ detailsVisible: false });
  render() {
    return (
      <div onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}>
        <img src={this.props.champ.file} />
        { this.state.detailsVisible && <ChampDetails champ={this.props.champ} /> }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const ChampDetails = ({champ}) => (
  <div>
    <p>Name: { champ.name } </p>
    <p>Role: { champ.role } </p>
    <p>Difficulty: { champ.diff } </p>
    <p>Price: { champ.price } </p>
  </div>
);
```

*^ Requires [class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/), otherwise put the class property assignments (`state`, `handleMouseEnter`, and `handleMouseLeave`) in a constructor.*

Comment: Thank you this actually makes so much more sense now, I was trying to use setState in <img mouseover = whic hwasnt going anywhere, thanks again

Comment: @matthewg You can use `<img onMouseOver={e => this.setState(...)} />` but its generally recommended to create a handler function like my example. Either way the important part to understand is that a handler attribute such as `onMouseOver` should be a *reference to a function*, not a function call like `onMouseOver={this.setState(...)}` or any arbitrary JS code.

Comment: @matthewg Mark answered questions please :)